# Using LoggingLevelSwitch configured in app.config to switch level at runtime

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

I'm trying to implement log level switching at runtime. Using SeriLog's LoggingLevelSwitch works fine if I configure it from code like below.

```
var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch(LogEventLevel.Verbose);
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
    .CreateLogger();
logger.Verbose("This gets logged.");
levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning;
logger.Verbose("This does not.");
```

Now I want to move the level switch configuration to app.config, leaving only `new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.AppSettings();` in code. Adding following to app.config does limit the level but I cannot find the way to change this while my program is running.

```
<add key="serilog:level-switch:$mySwitch" value="Warning" />
<add key="serilog:minimum-level:controlled-by" value="$mySwitch" />
```

I've tried

- just setting the value in app.config (in case SeriLog re-reads the
  configuration),
- pause the program, setting the value in app.config and calling
  `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");` (in case it does re-read but needs a bit of incentive)
- finding a way to access the LoggingLevelSwitch created by SeriLog when reading the app.config (there doesn't seem to be any properties available that would let you poke around the generated configuration)

To clarify, ideally I want SeriLog to automatically re-read the config and update the log level itself. It is also acceptable to get a reference to internal switch; this way I keep the switch settings in app.config, but I have to create a mechanism to re-read the setting when changed.

I would like to avoid configuring switch from code, as well as keep the app.config settings in line with how other SeriLog settings are done (i.e. no custom app.config properties).

Comment: Could you please clarify, what is the desired scenario: 1. You want to update the level in config and want Serilog to re-read the configuration. 2. You want to solve it purely from the code, by getting access to the switch somehow and setting the new log level?

Comment: Have you found a solution?